# Sum of all vectors in a subspace of a vector space over a finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $F_n$ be a finite field where $n$ is a power of $2$.

Let $F_n^k$ be the set of all vectors of length $k$ over $F_n$, where $k \geq 2$.

Now, I know that the sum of all the vectors in $F_n^k$ is equal to the zero vector.

My question is the following;

What if we take a subspace of $F_n^k$, where the dimension of the subspace is greater than $1$? Is the sum still the zero vector?

My thoughts are that as this subspace is a vector space in its own right, then the same result should hold? I’m just unsure!

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: How would I show this, though?

Comment: Take a basis $v_1,...,v_m$ of the subspace. The number of elements of the subpace that have the same $i$-th coordinate is equal to $|F_n|^{m-1}$, which is even. Therefore, when you add all the vectors that value of the coordinate is added an even number of times. Since the characteristic is $2$, the result is zero.

Comment: Why is the number of elements which have the same $i$-th coordinate $|F_n|^{m-1}$?